# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/public/main.html' at Error (native)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

[image]

This is my `server.js` file:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();  
app 
    .use(express.static('./public'))
    .get('*',function (req,res) {
        res.sendfile('/public/main.html');
        })
 .listen(3000);
```

This is my `main.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <titel>Contacts</titel>
    <base href'/'> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
         <div class="page-header">
             <h1>Contatcs</h1>
         </div>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

And the folder structure:

[image]

Comment: It seems like the path to "'/public/main.html'" is wrong.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since both the server and the index file are INSIDE the "public" directory, you can simply use :

```
res.sendfile('./main.html');
```

To answer the question in the comments : In Express 4.x, the `sendfile` method was replaced by the `sendFile` method (all lowercase -> camelCase). Probably just an oversight in early versions, that got fixed in the latter.

Comment: this not working for me,what is the different between res.sendFile() and res.sendfile() methods?

Comment: @teranteshara Thanks for pointing that out, improved my answer.

Comment: what if the index file were inside another directory? how would you "go back/out" of the public directory and into another directory to find it?

Comment: @tobbeLobb Yes, for example ./../html/main.html. Though it would probably be better to take server.js out of public, not sure why it was there in the OP's dir structure.

Answer (score 7):

__dirname has been deprecated and the suggested solutions may not work currently (August 2021). In Express 4.x this has been simplified and you wouldn't need to use 'path' module, you just have to specify a root option like this:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('main.html', {root: 'public'});
});
```

Comment: We're in 2023 and __dir is not deprecated node v19

Answer (score 5):

For me using the "." in the path didn't work, instead, I tweaked it as:

```
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/main.html');
```

Comment: What value does "__dirname" represent?

Answer (score 3):

You missed the **dot**. Keep in mind relative directory is

```
res.sendfile('./public/main.html');
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue when I referred to `dist` folder.
the relative path to index.html was:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/project-name/index.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
res.sendfile('/public/main.html');
```

should be changed to

```
res.sendfile('./public/main.html');
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution works for me:

```
res.sendfile('./main.html');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this : `res.sendFile(__dirname + '/main.html');`
It'll definitely work. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
server.js


const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/projectName'));

app.post('/*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname +  '/dist/projectName/index.html');
});
app.listen(4200);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  It appears that my client code was somehow not "in sync" with my server code (I'm not too familiar with the inner workings of node/express/angular and how they affect each other so "in sync" is the best I can do).  I had only rebuilt my server code (after having added one nodejs library and updated another, among other server code changes) with this:

`npm run build.server` (for my project this only builds server side.  I run this sometimes when I'm testing server changes because rebuilding the client code as well, without a watch, can take a long time)

Once I rebuilt the client code this issue was resolved:

`npm run build -- dev` (for my project this builds everything, server and client code)

Answer (score 1):

For my case I used nestjs with **ServeStaticModule** and it helps to **add serveRoot option**:

```
ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
    // play with options below
    rootPath: path.resolve(`./src/assets`), // I prefer to use resolve in your case it can be better to use path.join
    serveRoot: '/assets',
})
```

So then I found files on:  http://localhost:3000/assets/1.png

Other options : [ServeStaticModuleOptions](https://github.com/nestjs/serve-static/blob/master/lib/interfaces/serve-static-options.interface.ts)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After emailing heroku, mine was a case sensitivity problem. One of my files was in all caps, and i had to make adjustments from there.

Answer (score 0):

Though OP's cause is different for this error I got the same error due to a different reason so I am posting this for other's who come here.

I had a server-side shell script that was changing the current directory. Since we use relative paths in `sendfile` I started seeing this error after this script would run. This shell script was being run by Node.

Answer (score 0):

l was also face same kind of problem. And did all the above solution but nothing has happened. Then I deleted my public, `index.html` file and recreate it and use this code:

```js
return res.sendFile( __dirname + '/public/index.html');
```

Answer (score -1):

my server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/projectName'));

app.get('/*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname +  '/dist/projectName/index.html');
});
app.listen(4200);
```