# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/var/task/src/functions/public/home.html'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, netlify

I'm trying to deploy [my express based site on netlify](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2018/09/13/how-to-run-express.js-apps-with-netlify-functions/)
and my local directory look like this:

[image: directory image]

and my netlify.toml looks like this:

```
[build]
  functions="functions"

 [[redirects]]
   to="/.netlify/functions/_app/:splat"
   from="/*"
   status=200
```

It works fine when I run it locally using `netlify dev` 
but when I deploy the site on netlify
it shows this error:

[image]

I've even tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36340747/error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-stat-public-main-html-at-error-nat/36341844) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39492259/enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-stat-error-with-express-middleware) approach but it isn't seem to work in my case
I'm a beginner so I'm not quite sure what mistake I'm making, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Got the same problem, have you found a solution? I think the problem is that the non-function files were not deployed to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing line 14 : `app.use("/", router)` to

```
app.use('/.netlify/functions/_app', router);  // path must route to lambda
```